# Django. Сохранение файлов на сервер в определенные папки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, django, url

Всем привет. Создаю api для загрузки файлов на сервер через django rest framework. Есть две модели:

```
class Work(models.Model):
    N = models.IntegerField()
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class File(models.Model):
    work = models.ForeignKey(Work, default=None);
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None);
    file = models.FileField(verbose_name='file', upload_to='files/')
```

У каждой модели Work есть уникальное значение N. Одна Работа может иметь большое количество Файлов. 
Мне нужно сохранять данные в формате

> files/<номер N у привязанной File>/filename'

Пока что все кидаются в одну кучу 'files/'

Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 0):

В параметр [upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) можно передать функцию

```
from os import path
from django.conf import settings

def upload_to(instance, filename):
    return path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'files',
                     instance.work.N, filename)


class File(models.Model):
    work = models.ForeignKey(Work, default=None);
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None);
    file = models.FileField(verbose_name='file', upload_to=upload_to)
```